# Error while trying to use get .year from an column

Tags: pandas, datetime

When I'm trying to get all years from by database, Python throws an error:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['year'] = [i.year for i in df.index]
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html):

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).year
```

In your solution assign back `df.index`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['year'] = [i.year for i in df.index]
```